# How to change text according to percent indicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a percent indicator and I want to show its percent in a text widget with percent type(like 90%) when its property is 9.0
something like this. As you can see its percent is out of its area and it shows the current percent

[image]

Here is my indicator:

```
  child: LinearPercentIndicator(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
              animation: true,
              lineHeight: 6.0,
              animationDuration: 2000,
              percent: 0.6,
              linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xffD2D9EC),
            ),
```

I want to convert percent: `0.6,` to an int. And then show it in a text widget and I want to do exactly the opposite of that. It means I want to convert an int to a double and show it in indicator percent. I want to change it once, like when the user is coming to the page. Take it from API and show it in there.

Comment: could you post code which you have tried so far

Comment: sure,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: now i did please read the code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var percentValue = 0.6;

child: LinearPercentIndicator(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
              animation: true,
              lineHeight: 6.0,
              animationDuration: 2000,
              percent: percentValue,
              linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xffD2D9EC),
            ),


Text(_determineText(percentValue), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))


_determineText(percentValue){
 var value = percentValue * 100; //0.6 -> 60
 return (‘%’+(value.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code to convert decimal to percent to an Int and display it on the `Text` widget. The idea is to bind the percentage to a common value and the convert it to display into a text. I am using a `Stateful Widget` and a `Slider` to change percentage value but you can always bind to any source like AOI response time or something like that.

Here is the sample code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';

void main() {
  //Run the App Widget
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Demo App",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Demo App"),
        ),
        body: Demo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  double _value = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              '${(_value * 100.0).toInt()}%',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            LinearPercentIndicator(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
              lineHeight: 50.0,
              animationDuration: 2000,
              percent: _value,
              linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.butt,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xffD2D9EC),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Slider(
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (value) => {
                setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                })
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the output -

[image: Demo App Ouput]

This will give you an idea of how to proceed towards the solution you want.

Comment: thank you for your effort but August Kimo's answer is exactly what i'm looking for i voteup your answer

Answer (score -1):

In This You use SeekBar,And use SeekBar Listner in Listner You Can Change Text on Textview.

// sbVolum is id of seekbar

````
this.sbVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar see`enter code here`kBar) {
            }

            public void onStopTracki`enter code here`ngTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean z) {
              // in this you can change text
            }
        });
```
````

Comment: If you read the tags it's saying flutter and dart. Not Java